# Events WebPart & Overlays in SPO

Tags: sharepoint-online, calendar, sharepoint-calendar, overlay

I have SPO and using modern sites, I am needing to view overlay calendars in the webpart on the homepage and realised the group calendars cant be achieved with this.

So using the events webpart I have created a calendar for site A and this has been connected with Site B's calendar.

However in the events webpart on the homepage only shows site A events. If you open the list you can see both events sitting there from Site A & Site B.

How can i see the events from Site B in the webpart as well?

Thanks